# How to set a specific font size on devices using CSS?

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to set a specific (large) monospace font on iOS/iPhone. In CSS I've set `font-family:  monospace` (which Steven fixed recently) and `font-size: 56pt` but it doesn't work (I get a pretty small monospace font). I've also tried with `font-size: 200%` which also just gave a small font.

Since it is quite slow to find right size by trial and error testing on the device, is there a way to understand exactly what font gets selected on the device based on the css definition?

This will also help check up against Apple/Android documentation to ensure picking supported sizes. I searched in the CN1 code as well but didn't find any code doing the conversion.

Comment: Monospace is a system font and as such only supports three sizes: small, medium and large. It doesn't support arbitrary sizes. This is only supported by the truetype fonts

Comment: Thanks Shai. I don’t really understand what a system font signifies on an iOS device. In any case, CSS should throw an error. And it would be really useful with documentation to help avoid wasting time on trial and error. Alternatively sharing where in the CN1 code the transformation from CSS to platform fonts happen.

Comment: This is pretty obvious in the designer tool UI. The CSS stuff was layered on top of it so some details get lost in the process. I'm not sure if an exception is something we can do for some of these edge cases but feel free to file an issue on that. Generally using the `native:` fonts allows you to resize to any size and so does using a TTF of your own

Comment: I don't use the designer tool anymore, but it doesn't give you the device font used for e.g. Monospace Medium. I read your answer to mean there is no way I can learn what CSS code leads to which actual fonts on the device. To be honest, I find this lack of transparency difficult to understand given how important fonts and sizes are for the user experience.

Comment: No. I said that monospace is a system font which is a special case. We don't have as much control of monospace fonts by design. If you want to get control just download a monospace fornt TTF and embed it in your project to get 100% control.

Comment: OK, but I still don't understand exactly how it is determined which device font gets used. I thought the mapping between a CN1 System font and the actual device font was done by CN1 and not controlled by iOS.

Comment: We do that but system fonts are deep in old code with a lot of historic dependencies. Because of that we just can't control them. I think the right solution for this is to add a `native:` font mapping for the builtin monospace font which is an omission in the newer font engine. You can file an RFE for that.